# Read N lines from a file

Tags: python, loops, io

so for class we have to start out our problem doing this:

> Write a function that takes as its input a filename, and an integer. The file should open the file and read in the first number of lines given as the second argument. (You'll need to have a variable to use as a counter for this part).

It's very basic and I figure a loop is needed but I can't figure out how to incorporate a loop into the question. What I've tried doesn't work and it's been about 3 hours and the best I can come up with is

```
def filewrite(textfile,line):
    infile=open(textfile,'r',encoding='utf-8')
    text=infile.readline(line)
    print(text)
```

however that doesn't get me to what I need for the function. It's still early in my intro to python class so basic code is all we have worked with.

Comment: Loops are fundamental in programming. If you feel you cannot solve a program that uses loops, stop and go back to the loops chapter of your textbook.

Comment: It sounds like you should read the lines to the nth line.  (So if `n` was 3, you would read the first three lines then stop).  Your attempt makes it look like you're trying to read only the nth line. (As an aside, the argument to [`readline`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOBase.readline) limits the number of *characters* that will be read from the file)

Comment: @davedwards That's not what the argument to [`readlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.IOBase.readlines) does either.

Comment: You're right that the argument to readline limits the number of characters. I just can't get my head around how to use a loop and counter to get the function to accept a parameter and use said parameter to print out that many lines. I keep getting the function to print out n number of characters..

Answer (score 0):

There are two basic looping strategies you could use here:

1. you could count up to `n`, reading lines as you go
2. you could read lines from file, keeping track of how many you've read, and stop when you reach a certain number.

---

```
def filewrite(textfile, n):
    with open(textfile) as infile:
        for _ in range(n):
            print(infile.readline(), end='')
    print()
```

---

```
def filewrite(textfile, n):
    with open(textfile) as infile:
        counter = 0
        for line in infile:
            if counter >= n:
                break
            print(line, end='')
            counter += 1
```

---

The first is obviously more readable, and since `readline` will just return an empty string if it runs out of lines, it's safe to use even if the user asks for more lines than the infile has.

Here I'm also using a [context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) to make sure the files are closed when I'm done with them.

---

Here's a version without the stuff you don't recognize

```
def filewrite(textfile, n):
    infile = open(textfile)
    count = 0
    while count < n:
        print(infile.readline())
        count += 1
    infile.close()
```

Comment: Note: The second approach would, canonically, use `enumerate` rather than maintaining the counter variable manually, though for a class assignment, it's possible `enumerate` hasn't been introduced yet. A truly canonical approach would just use `itertools.islice` and avoid a counter variable of any kind (well, avoid any visible in Python, obviously under the hood it's tracking that info, but you don't see it).

Comment: @ShadowRanger good point.  I wanted to show that way because of the "(You'll need to have a variable to use as a counter for this part)." part of the question.

Comment: I'm not going to doubt anyone here and I appreciate what I am sure are correct codes. But in our class I've never seen "with" "break" "enumerate" "for" "end=' '" which is why this problem has me stumped and our professor doesn't like it when we use stuff he hasn't asked us to use

Comment: @LittleAuditorium What kind of loops are you familiar with if not `for` loops?  You could do this using a `while` loop, but that would sort of be like using a screwdriver to pound nails.

Comment: whoops I didn't mean to include "for". yeah we use "for" loops. Your second solution looks something similar to what we've gone over in class. but with "break" in there I'm not sure what that does and same goes for "end+' '"

Comment: `break` is a control flow statement that "breaks" the execution out of a loop prematurely.  You can [read about it here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).  `print` takes a keyword argument `end` that changes the character that `print` prints after the primary argument.  By default `end='\n'`, but since the lines in the file already end with `\n`, that would cause gaps in our output.

Comment: ok your update prints out the n number of lines thank you so much. Because I actually want to learn the material rather than just take an answer, would you mind answering if the whole point of the "while" function is to keep printing out lines until the counter==n?

Comment: @LittleAuditorium Yes. more specifically, `while` loops are of the form `while <expression>: <code>`.  An expression is basically code that evaluates to some value. The `while` loop will check if the expression evaluates to some truthy value. If it does, the `code` will be executed, the expression checked again, etc.  If not, then execution will move past the contents of the `while` loop, potentially never interpreting any of it.  So here, our `while` loop will keep looping until `count >= n`